# Where does the re-routing take place in this case?

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx with AngularJS / node.js

When I visit the website

```
https://domainxyz/login
```

it automatically tries to open https://domainxyz/app.html

I would like to change the link to "app-new.html".

But I don't see where to do that.

My web app was developed by somebody else, and I'm just trying to fix it, so I'm not sure where he implemented this routing.

My sites-available (/etc/nginx/) looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domainxyz www.domainxyz; 
    return 301 https://domainxyz$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

        server_name domainxyz www.domainxyz;
        location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        location / {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                     proxy_http_version 1.1;
                     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                     proxy_set_header Host $host;
                     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    location /hospital {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    location /old_doc {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    location /webrtc {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    location /docs {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?r=$request_uri;

        }
    location /docs/admin/ {                                          
         try_files $uri $uri/ /docs/admin/index.php?$is_args$args;
    }  
    location /docs/patient/ {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /docs/patient/index.php?$is_args$args;
        }
    location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
        rewrite "^/login" doc-register.html last; 
        rewrite "^/logout" doc-register.html last;
        rewrite "^/register" doc-register.html last;
        rewrite "^/dashboard" doctor.html last;
        rewrite "^/waiting-room" doctor.html last;
         rewrite "^/update-tan" doctor.html last;
        rewrite "^/tans" doctor.html last;
        rewrite "^/create-tan" doctor.html last;
        rewrite "^/profile" doctor.html last;
        rewrite "^/system-check" doctor.html last;
        rewrite "^/plogin" pindex.html last;
        rewrite "^/pdashboard" pindex.html last;
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainxyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainxyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And my sites-enabled looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domainxyz www.domainxyz; 
    return 301 https://domainxyz$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

        server_name domainxyz www.domainxyz;

        location / {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                     proxy_http_version 1.1;
                     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                     proxy_set_header Host $host;
                     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    location /hospital {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    location /old_doc {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    location /webrtc {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    location /docs {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?r=$request_uri;

        }
        location /docs/admin/ {                                          
         try_files $uri $uri/ /docs/admin/index.php?$is_args$args;
    }  
    location /login {                                          
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }  
    location /docs/patient/ {
                 try_files $uri $uri/ /docs/patient/index.php?$is_args$args;
        }
    location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
        rewrite "^/login" doc-register.html last;
        rewrite "^/reset" doc-register.html last;
        rewrite "^/logout" doc-register.html last;
        rewrite "^/register" doc-register.html last;
        rewrite "^/dashboard" /doctor.html last;
        rewrite "^/waiting-room" /doctor.html last;
         rewrite "^/update-tan" /doctor.html last;
        rewrite "^/tans" /doctor.html last;
        rewrite "^/create-tan" /doctor.html last;
        rewrite "^/profile" /doctor.html last;
        rewrite "^/system-check" /doctor.html last;
        rewrite "^/plogin" /pindex.html last;
        rewrite "^/tan" /pindex.html last;
        rewrite "^/pdashboard" /patient.html last;
        rewrite "^/wartezimmer" /patient.html last;
        rewrite "^/psystem-check" /patient.html last;
        rewrite "^/videosprechstunde" /videostream.html last;
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainxyz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainxyz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
        # Security headers
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
# add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
# add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
# add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' www.google-analytics.com ajax.googleapis.com www.google.com google.com gstatic.com www.gstatic.com connect.facebook.net facebook.com;";
# add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
# add_header Referrer-Policy "origin";

}
```

What else could I check?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that changing the sites-enabled file is correct, however, a leading / was missing:

```
rewrite "^/login" /doc-register.html last;
```

And it's not the server that needs to be restarted, but nginx!!!

So instead of using

```
pm2 stop server
pm2 start server
```

... I just used this:

```
killall nginx
nginx
```

Then it would work.

Note to myself: I am the greatest debugger in the world.